# CRUD repository not working in a "simple" java class

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring-boot application with CRUD repository and a mysql database. When I use this repositories in a REST controller, I have no problems but I need to use one in a simple java class but it doesn't work.

I want to load all the residentStatEntities in a List to write in a CSV file but I can't load it.

Here are my code :

CRUD repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ResidentStatDBRepository extends CrudRepository<ResidentStatEntity, Long> {
    List<ResidentStatEntity> findAll();
}
```

Java class :

```
public class ResetDB {

    /**
     * CRUD Repository
     */
    @Autowired
    private  ResidentStatDBRepository residentStatDBRepository;



    /**
     * Delete DB and save his content in a CSV file
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void save()throws Exception{
        //open file
        String csvFile = "residentStat.csv";
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile, true);
        //get list of all stat
        List<ResidentStatEntity> residentStatEntities = residentStatDBRepository.findAll();
}
```

Here are the message print in the console :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.sems.ResetDB.save(ResetDB.java:36)
    at com.example.sems.SemsApplication$1.run(SemsApplication.java:52)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Here is where I use the ResetDB class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SemsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SemsApplication.class, args);
        int MINUTES = 1; // The delay in minutes
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() { // Function runs every MINUTES minutes.
                try{
                    new ResetDB().save();
                    System.out.println("ok");
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000 * 60 * MINUTES);
        // 1000 milliseconds in a second * 60 per minute * the MINUTES variable.
    }
}
```

I call this function every minutes maybe the problem is because it's in the main method ?

Thanks in advance for you answer :)

Comment: how did you instantiate your ResetDB class?

Comment: @Stultuske ResetDB resetdb = new ResetDB(); and then I call the method like this : resetdb.save();

Comment: @Flo_H99 Spring's component scan is probably not picking up the repository. Check [ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) and [EnableJpaRepositories("path.to.your.repo")](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html) annotations.

Answer (score 0):

ResetDB is not a spring managed bean.

Annotate ResetDB with @Component it should solve the problem.

Comment: doubtful. if it's not a spring managed bean, chances are small that it's autowired, so it'll likely take more than just adding that annotation

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: @Flo_H99 that is because that is only a part of the answer.

Comment: @Flo_H99  Are you getting the same error?

Comment: @Santoshb yes and I also tried the soluce of Stultuske, I will edit my question to show also when I call the method save

Comment: Add private @Autowired ResetDB resetDB

Replace new ResetDB() with resetDB

Answer (score 0):

In order for `ResetDB` to be able to manage your Bean using Spring injection, `ResetDB` itself must be instantiated by that system.

Add the `@Component` annotation to your `ResetDB` class, and have your instance of `ResetDB` autowired as well.